# Trouble with android navigation Drawer

Tags: android

I have created a simple navigation drawer using this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer) , the items in the nav drawer link to their respective fragments, but once i click on an item in the nav drawer i want it to take me to ie a list view. As far i see its that  it only links to a java class that extends Fragment, as soon as i mention extend ListFragment it freaks out.

Comment: What do you mean with freaks out? Do you have some stacktrace, error or something like that?

Comment: the error i am getting when i hover over is incompatible types, and when i try run the project i get
error: incompatible types
required: Fragment
found:    EastgateFragment
as far as i understand is that i link the item in the nav drawer to a fragment, and inside that fragment i must link to another java class, is that right. If so I have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the NavigationDrawer I use:

First of all I set a Click listener to the ListView inside the NavigationDrawer

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

DrawerItemClickListener its a custom class

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }
```

This calls to `selectItem(int position)`

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new FirstFragment());
            setTitle("First");
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new SecondFragment());
            setTitle("Second");
            break;
        case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new ThirdFragment());
            setTitle("Third");
            break;
        }

        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mRelativeLayout);
    }
```

Here you can set any Fragment of any kind you want. With this you won't have any Fragment type mismatch.

Also you can follow an official NavigationDrawer example provided by Android developers.

> http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for this but i still cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: maybe im looking at it wrong, is there a better way of doing what i want to do?

Comment: Yes, you can use a simple fragment that contains a ListView, and reference it on the onCreateView method of your Fragment lifecycle. Anyway what I´ve shown you it's a normal NavigationDrawer implementation.

Comment: @TheCrazyZimbo did you get it right at the end? Do you need more help?

Comment: hey bud, well i had to give it a break for a lil while, ill carry on in a few days, thanx tho, if i get stuck ill shout, have u got skype or sumn we can chat on??

Comment: Ok, no problem. I´ll give you this email asier@irontec.com so you can get in touch if needed. Anyway the comment system will soon create a chat room that can be accessible from a link in those comments.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, ill save your email, and chat with you, ill probably run into more issues as i go and learn more, but for now i found out what i was doing wrong, i had forgotten to add my activity to the manifest file haha lol...

Comment: Ok. No problem with me, I'll try to help on everything I can. By the way, if my answer helped you solving the issue can you accept it? Thanks!